# Illustrator: How do I create a clipping mask with 2 paths?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to create a clipping mask to ensure a shape doesn't spill over outside of the containing shape. Here's the image I am working on:

[image]

I would like the L shape to remain inside the blue box. I will later add a little animation which requires the L shape to be larger.

Here is how I am attempting to do this:

1. Select both of the paths
2. Object > Clipping Mask > Make

But this doesn't produce the desired results. Instead the blue background shape disappears.

Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot of what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group the background and the L.

Make another rectangle in front of the group, and use that as the clipping mask.

[image]

Comment: I took the freedom to edit in a crucial detail that apparently stumped the OP. Feel free to re-edit if you think I butchered your post!

Comment: No that's absolutely fine @Vincent ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the L.
2. Cut.
3. Select the blue shape.
4. Turn on Draw Inside mode by hitting the rightmost of the three buttons near the bottom of the toolbar.
5. edit>paste in place
6. Turn off Draw Inside mode by hitting one of the other two buttons in its row. Probably Draw Above.

Internally this makes a clipping mask just like any other. But it doesn't remove the clipping mask's fill or stroke.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you need to move the blue object on top of the "L" shaped one and then select these both> Clipping Mask > Make a mask

(you can use these shortcuts > Ctrl+X and then Ctrl+F to cut the blue shape out and then paste it on top of everything in the same position. )

Hope it's gonna help! :)

Answer (score -3):

1. Drop down Menu: Object > Clipping Mask > Make
2. Shortcut Key: Command > 7
3. Layer Panel: Make/Release Clipping Mask icon at the bottom
4. Right click: highlight all objects and select Make Clipping Mask

Please find the link for StepbyStep

https://99designs.com/blog/design-tutorials/adobe-illustrator-tutorial-clipping-mask-and-compound-path/

Comment: How does this answer the question? You're simply describing the steps to make a clipping mask, OP *already* knows how to do this (it says how in the question)